# Extract text based on its coordinates from converting multiple PDF files from a folder using pdfminer

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates, nested-lists, pdfminer

I want to extract text based on it's coordinates from converting multiple PDF files from a folder using `pdfminer` and storing my result into a list or a dictionary. I initially managed to convert a single file, and was able to extract text based on its coordinates.

I must say I'm not really good at Python but I'm trying my best. Really appreciate if somebody can tell me how to fix following code:

```
import os
import glob
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfdevice import PDFDevice
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
import pdfminer
from cStringIO import StringIO


directory = os.path.abspath('./')
pdfFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.pdf'))

resourceManager = PDFResourceManager()
returnString = StringIO()
codec = 'utf-8'
laParams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(resourceManager, laparams=laParams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resourceManager, device)


maxPages = 0
caching = True
pageNums=set()

for one_pdf in pdfFiles:
    print("Processing file: " + str(one_pdf))
    fp = file(one_pdf, 'rb')
    name = "one_pdf"

    lst =[]
    def parse_obj(lt_objs):
        for one_pdf in enumerate(pdfFiles):
            for obj in lt_objs:
                if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
                    print "%6d, %6d, %s" % (obj.bbox[0], obj.bbox[1], obj.get_text().replace('\n', '_'))
                    lst.append([one_pdf,[[obj.bbox[0],obj.bbox[1]], obj.get_text()]])

                elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
                    parse_obj(obj._objs)

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pageNums, maxpages=maxPages,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):

            interpreter.process_page(page)
            layout = device.get_result()

            parse_obj(layout._objs)

device.close()
returnString.close()
```

The code outputs the name of the PDF within the given folder followed by the PDF text layout. Here is where I haven't been able to successfully store the result into a nested list or a dictionary of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out how to store pdf names as keys and their contents along with content's coordinates into a dictionary (pdf_dict).

```
lst=[]
dicts_from_file =[]
pdf_dict = {}

for one_pdf in pdfFiles:
#print("Processing file: " + str(one_pdf))
fp = file(one_pdf, 'rb')
name = str(one_pdf)
head, tail = os.path.split(name)
dicts_from_file.append({tail})

def parse_obj(lt_objs):
    for obj in lt_objs:
        if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):
            lst.append([[obj.bbox[0],obj.bbox[1]],obj.get_text().replace('\n', '')])
            pdf_dict.update( {tail : lst} )


        elif isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTFigure):
            parse_obj(obj._objs)
            return []

for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pageNums, maxpages=maxPages, password=password,caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()

    parse_obj(layout._objs)

device.close()
returnString.close()
```

Comment: Is there a way to read text from based on coordinates i have, using pdfminer?